# Pagination/Infinite Scroll with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, pagination, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have sub-nodes of a node which I created with `childByAutoId()`. I am trying to do pagination for using it in TableView however I couldn't figure out how.

My database looks like this:

```
- items
   -KKM7Fv8H7dCiD2xChYB
      - userID : 1231231

   -KKM7Fv8H7dCiD2MVaVt
   -KKM7Fv8H7dCiDFJfska
```

Is the a way that I can give it a 'items per page count' and retrieve data accordingly? What is the best way of doing infinite scroll/pagination

```
items.queryOrderedByChild("userId").queryEqualToValue(key).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
```

Comment: If you use `queryLimitedToFirst:` you can retrieve a limited number of children. For subsequent pages, you would then use `queryStartingAtValue:`. All relevant methods are documented in the [reference guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_database_query.html#method-detail). I also recommend searching for "firebase & pagination", since this topic has been discussed regularly before.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add last timestamp with each sub node and then query

```
firebaseRef.child("user_id").queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryEnding(atValue: lastTimeStamp - 1).queryLimited(toLast: 10).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in })
```