# How do I Load in batches the Firebase EqualTo() Query?

Tags: node.js, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am loading my firebase data into a UITableView would like to load my data in batches as the user scrolls similar to the answers found here [batch load firebase query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41562765/9367155) and here [Firebase load in chunks](https://medium.com/@mvuksano/advanced-queries-in-firebase-a50f563179dd)

The query I would like to modify like this however I would like to add in some kind of `queryEnding(atValue: )` which would enable to me to load the next set of batches.

```
   query = self.database.reference(withPath: "PostIDS").queryOrdered(byChild: "userID").queryEqual(toValue: userID).queryLimited(toLast: 2)
```

My Data structure looks something like this

```
PostIDS
   -PostID1
       -userID: userID1
   -PostID2
       -userID: userID2
   -PostID3
        -userID: userID3
    .
    . 
    . 
    .
    .
    .
   -PostID100
        -userID: userID100
```

How would one go about loading in a batches the results of a `.queryEqual(toValue:)` query. Thank you